# HTML formatting gets ruined when I clone a section

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button that when clicked will clone a section of a form and append it. However when it gets appended my formatting/css gets messed up.

Here is my HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="newfacility.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Facility</legend>
        <label for="facilitynumber">Facility Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="facilitynumber" name="facilitynumber" value=""><br />
        <label for="facilityname">Facility name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="facilityname" name="facilityname" value=""><br />
        <label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="" /><br />
            <div id="facility_section_info">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Facility Section Information</legend>
                    <label for="designatedroofarea">Designated Roof Area: </label>
                    <input id="designatedroofarea" type="text" name="designatedroofarea"/><br />
                    <div id="roofcomponent">
                        <fieldset>
                            <table id="component_table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Component</th>
                                        <th>Component Type</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="component_tb">
                                    <tr id="row0">
                                        <td>component name</td>
                                        <td>component type</td> 
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <input type="button" value="+" id="addRows" class="addRows"/>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" value="Add New Section" id="addSection" class="addSection"/>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Create" name="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:grey;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left:20px;
}

label {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 200px;
}

table{
    width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

th{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
}

tr {
    padding: 1px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

td{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

and my JQuery function can be seen in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80ufj7f7/).

How can I fix it so that when I clone and append a section my formatting will not change?

Comment: So, I know you got an accepted answer but I wanted to let you know the exact reason your formatting got messed up. In this line: `var $sectionClone = $section.clone(true).find("*[id]").andSelf().each(function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + $cloneID); });` you are setting `$sectionClone` to an array of objects that `find()` and `andSelf()` identify. This breaks your element hieirarchy. You needed to split this to two lines: one which sets the clone area, and one which goes through each element and sets an updated ID. A fiddle with just that change: https://jsfiddle.net/jywan2te/

Comment: Hmm, interesting, thank you for bringing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cloning script is flawed.

`var $section = $("#facility_section_info").clone();`

You should be cloning the thing inside (the first `<fieldset>`), then appending it to your wrapper.

Please look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhf3nykk/1/).

Comment: I took a little bit of a different approach, but this was exactly the issue thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should clone on click - not at beginning
I changed the code a little:
https://jsfiddle.net/80ufj7f7/3/

I also made minor changes which were not required, you dont need to apply them

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   var section = $("#facility_section_info");
   var cloneID = 1; 
   $( ".addSection" ).click(function() { 
     var sectionClone = section.clone(true);
     sectionClone.find("*[id]").each(function() { $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + cloneID); });
     section.append(sectionClone);
     cloneID++; 
   });
});
```

Comment: The reason I was cloning before click is because I need the original state of the section before anything else is added or changed. For example if you notice my `+` button if I were to add rows to my original table or add anything into my input fields and then add a new section, it would clone the extra rows + any text in my input fields.